# UINavigationBar leads to Crash..!

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

APPLICATION : 
My application has three pages Page A,Page B and Page C.

WHAT I DID : 
I can individually link Page A to Page B and Page A to Page C.

PROBLEM: 
I am not able to link from Page A to C when i come back from B to A.

What should I do?

Your Suggestion and advise is most welcome. Waiting for ur reply. Thanks

Comment: page what?  are you talking about UIViews?  Are you using UINavigationController?

Comment: Yes Stephen, i m using UIViews and UINavigationController.Actually i m a newbie in iphone programming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer actually problem was not with UINavigation Bar but with NSTimer which got invalidated before i unloaded the view. Thanks Guys Anyways